# Nature of function(increasing/decreasing)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Okay so I just wanted to ask the nature of this function $f(x)=\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}$ that is ;whether it will be decreasing or increasing. $$ 
$$
I know that if we diffrentiate a function with respect to x and and if we get the $f'(x)>0$ it is an increasing function and vice versa. Also if $f'(x)=0$ the function we diffrentiated has to be a constant function. $$
$$
So when I diffrentiate my function, I get $f'(x)=0$,so my function should be a constant function, but it's not. $$
$$
Am I thinking correctly? If not is there any simpler method to judge the nature of a function?

Comment: You made a mistake, if you differentiate correctly you will find that $f'(x) >0$ everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should find:
$$\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{4\,{e}^{2\,x}}{{\left( {e}^{2\,x}+1\right) }^{2}}$$
which is $>0$ for all real $x$

Comment: Got it! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For a simpler method (if you're allowed to make a couple of assumptions), notice that:
$$
f(x)
=\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}
= \frac{(e^{2x} + 1) - 2}{e^{2x} + 1}
= 1 - \frac{2}{e^{2x} + 1}
$$
Now suppose that $a < b$. Then observe that:
\begin{align*}
a < b
&\implies 2a < 2b \\
&\implies 0 < e^{2a} < e^{2b} &\begin{bmatrix}\text{since $g(x) = e^x$ is a strictly increasing} \\\text{function that is always positive}\end{bmatrix} \\
&\implies 1 < e^{2a} + 1 < e^{2b} + 1 \\
&\implies \frac{1}{e^{2a} + 1} > \frac{1}{e^{2b} + 1} &\begin{bmatrix}\text{since $h(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ is a strictly} \\ \text{decreasing function for all $x > 0$}\end{bmatrix} \\
&\implies \frac{-2}{e^{2a} + 1} < \frac{-2}{e^{2b} + 1} \\
&\implies 1 - \frac{2}{e^{2a} + 1} < 1 -\frac{2}{e^{2b} + 1} \\
&\implies f(a) < f(b)
\end{align*}
Hence, $f$ is strictly increasing.

Answer (score 0):

You probably did an arithmetic mistake.Remember:

$$(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)})'=\frac{g(x)f'(x)-g'(x)f(x)}{f(x)^2}$$

and of course $e>0$